# Как убрать при наведении на каталог поле 'Нет в наличии'

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребят подскажите, как убрать при наведении на каталог поле Нет в наличии, в Битриксе
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно узнать какой класс принадлежит блоку "Нет в наличии". Найти этот класс в стилях css и прописать display:none!important;
Если на примере, то вот так.

```
.block:hover{display:none!important;}
```

Comment: Arcadiy так не пойдёт, нужно найти соответствующую переменную и её убрать, проблема в том , что не знаю где она находится

Comment: вот так он должен выглядеть .block:hover{display:none!important;}

Comment: Ну выложили бы код вывода, люди бы поковырялись, глядишь помогли бы.

Comment: Проблема в данном случае более обширная, как мне кажется, ведь поле нет в наличии генерируется самим битриксом

Comment: Думается искать нужно вот эту строчку <span class="catalog-item-not-available"><?=GetMessage("CATALOG_NOT_AVAILABLE")?></span>

Comment: Где нибуть вот тут \bitrix\templates\store_minimal_red\components\bitrix\catalog\.default\bitrix\catalog.element\.default\template

Comment: нашёл вот такую строчку по подобному пути $notAvailableMessage = ($arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] != '' ? $arParams['MESS_NOT_AVAILABLE'] : GetMessageJS('CT_BCE_CATALOG_NOT_AVAILABLE')); её походу удалить или иное действие осуществить?

Comment: Возможно тут и правиться. Перед тем как править Backup создайте на всякий случай.

Comment: Пробуйте любые способы, но прежде бэкап сохраните, чтобы откатить можно было. Никто вам точного ответа не даст не видя полного кода, но скорее всего именно эта часть и отвечает.

Comment: удалил строку, но результата не дало

Comment: Кэш почистите, чтобы в памяти не оставалась информация

Comment: и смотрите под обычным пользователем

Comment: надпись исчезла при детальном просмотре, но не исчезла в анонсе

Comment: Еще ковыряйтесь и ищите такую же надпись

Comment: плохо конечно, что только в детальном просмотре убирается